# Error In Date Format Conversion

Tags: android, date

I want to convert the date from "2014-04-09 00:00:00" to "09-apr" but i am getting a force close.
I am getting error at this part [tvStartDate.setText(sdf.format(event.startDate + "\n"));]

Class

```
package com.megasys.roushfunway.adapter;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.megasys.roushfunway.R;
import com.megasys.roushfunway.database.Event;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EventListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<Event> eventList;
    String format = "dd-MMM";
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);

    public EventListAdapter(Context context, List<Event> eventList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.eventList = eventList;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return eventList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return eventList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        Event event = eventList.get(position);

        if (view == null)
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                    R.layout.view_event_list, parent, false);

        TextView tvStartDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_start_date);
        TextView tvEventId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_event_id);
        TextView tvLocation = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_location);

        tvStartDate.setText(sdf.format(event.startDate + "\n"));
        tvEventId.setText(event.eventId);
        tvLocation.setText(event.venue);

        return view;
    }

}
```

I want to convert the date from "2014-04-09 00:00:00" to "09-apr" but i am getting a force close.
I am getting error at this part [tvStartDate.setText(sdf.format(event.startDate + "\n"));]

Comment: Please paste the error log with question.

Answer (score 1):

```
tvStartDate.setText(sdf.format(event.startDate + "\n"));
```

You cannot format a `String`. It will use the unsupported `format(Object)` overload instead of `format(Date)` you need.

If `event.startDate` is a `Date`, just move the paren:

```
tvStartDate.setText(sdf.format(event.startDate) + "\n");
```

If it is e.g. a datetime string, use another `SimpleDateFormat` to parse it to a `Date` first and then format the parsed `Date`.